# How to set network name in Windows

Tags: windows

I am trying to setup a static name for my PC on my network so that I can SSH into my pc from linux like this: ssh me@mypc without using an IP address. When I do the arp command, I see a bunch of named devices, including some other Windows devices. How do I setup my PC so that it has a name in this list instead of an IP address?

Comment: What is running DNS on your network?

Comment: Not sure, it is just an ASUS router

Comment: Personal opinion, but in my experience, getting Windows to "self-identify" like what you are describing is a pain. It would likely be simpler to set up a static DNS server (any computer on the network that can be left on all the time will do) with something like [BIND](https://www.isc.org/bind/). Point your router to that server and have one or more name/IP entries to your local PC there.

Comment: If you want an overview of setting up BIND on Windows with a custom name, take a look a [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1239419/creating-a-custom-domain-on-my-wi-fi-network-with-a-windows-computer-and-apache). Just be sure to uncomment the line for "forwarders" in "named.conf" (i.e. remove the hash #) ex. `forwarders { 8.8.8.8; 8.8.4.4; };`. That will allow your local computers to continue to access the internet.

Comment: Of course if you use a Windows server, the DHCP server can be configured to update the DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

Enable NetBIOS in Windows:
http://ecross.mvps.org/howto/enable-netbios-over-tcp-ip-with-windows.htm

Without seeing your DNS server and your Windows PC, and your client, it's impossible to know what is the best way. You may be able to type a static value into your local name server, or it may be that enabling NetBIOS broadcasts is enough.