# How to Access Localhost in the Network

Tags: windows-10, xampp

Can anyone help me what to do, I don't have an idea.
I want to access my website in my localhost using other computer in the network, instead of typing 192.168.0.x, how can I access it using example.test?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45392044/11656450) answer on StackOverflow

Comment: Thank you. @MosheGross

Comment: Another solution is using a [local DNS server running the proper software e.g. BIND](https://superuser.com/q/1239419/302907).